# Role based security using APIs for filenet p8

Tags: java, api, filenet-p8, ibm-case-manager

I need to assign security dynamically using roles on case folders using Filenet p8 Java APIs.
I have tried to use the classes stated on knowledge center but still there is a missed part.
Anybody tried this approach?

Comment: Can you share more info like the error logs? Or the failure to launch logs?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what security setting you are try to achieve, if it is related to show and hide folders dynamically, this can help you.

I think the best way to achieve that is by using Filenet markingSet.
You can Add markingSet to some property of your folder, and set ActiveDirectory groups to each markingSet value.
Then you can just change the property value.
After you will do so, the security will change dynamically .
For example, if you will create a folder with property StateView.
Connect new markingSet(value 0 - x AD GROUP, value 1 - y AD group) for this property .
If the folder property StateView is stetted to 0, only x AD group can see it.
If you will update the value to 1, now only y AD group will be able to see it.
you can create your own logic